# Как построить URL из множества подкатегорий LARAVEL?

Tags: php, laravel, url, маршрутизация

уважаемые программисты!
Объясните пожалуйста, как грамотно построить URL из множества подкатегорий?

У меня есть страница - все категории (общее меню).

```
// роут
 Route::get('/category', 'CategoryController@index')->name('category.index');
// контроллер
public function index()
```

с этой странице, я должен перейти на .ru/category/odegda/zhenskaya
для этого у меня есть:

```
// роут
Route::get('/category/{alias?}', 'CategoryController@one')->name('category.one');
// контроллер
public function one($alias, Request $request)
// через ссылку
<a title="{{ $v['name'] }}" href="{{ route('category.one', $v['url']) }}">
```

но у меня не получается передать параметр (odegda/zhenskaya).
404 не найдено

Comment: Конечно, это описано в документации https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#parameters-encoded-forward-slashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Route::get('/category/{alias?}', 'CategoryController@one')->where('alias', '(.*)')->name('category.one');